# Two models in a view (with foreach)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, model

I have two classes - Student.cs and Lecturer.cs placed under Models. Now that in my razor view I have to place two classes together.

I know there's a method Tuple to solve the problem. But I do not know what to do next. What should I do with my @foreach?

Here's my code in cshtml.

```
@model Tuple<MVCApp1.Models.Student, MVCApp1.Models.Lecturer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MainPage";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

I'm using a table, below is my @foreach code section.

```
@foreach (var j in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td">@j.FirstName
                    </td>
                    <td>@j.MiddleName
                    </td>
                    <td>@j.LastName
                    </td>
```

I need to have 2 tables each with different attributes. First table from Student.cs and second table will be Lecturer.cs. 
I know there is something wrong with the @foreach but I just can't find any solution online. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple does not expose an iterator.

```
public class Tuple<T1> : IStructuralEquatable, IStructuralComparable, IComparable, ITuple
```

What you are after is a `ViewModel`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; } 
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

    // retreive from database
    model.Students = new List<Student>() { new Student()};
    model.Teachers = new List<Teacher>() { new Teacher()};

    return View(model);
}
```

Then you can structure your table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Middle</th>
        <th>Last</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var student in Model.Students)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@student.First</td>
            <td>@student.Middle</td>
            <td>@student.Last</td>
        </tr>
    }
    @foreach (var teacher in Model.Teachers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@teacher.First</td>
            <td>@teacher.Middle</td>
            <td>@teacher.Last</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Once you are comfortable with this, you can explore inheritance and Entity Framework TPH Table per hierarchy.

You could end up with something like this:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : Person
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrolledDate { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<Student> StudentsOnly { get; set; }
    public List<Person> StudentsAndTeachers { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    Context db = new Context();

    ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
    // You could collect just the students
    model.StudentsOnly = db.People.OfType<Student>().ToList();
    // Or all of them
    model.StudentsAndTeachers = db.People.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Then you would only have to iterate through the single list of people, if you only needed to display their names.

```
<table>
    ...
    @foreach (var person in Model.StudentsAndTeachers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@person.First</td>
            <td>@person.Middle</td>
            <td>@person.Last</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: You could make a new folder in your Project under `/ViewModels/ViewModel.cs` or more specific naming for that page. As it's a table, how about `ListingViewModel.cs`

Comment: `new List<Student>() { new Student()};` populate here and assign to ViewModel like you would usually.

Comment: what do i need to do in my view? i'm getting error. at the first @foreach it says does not contain a definition for Student.

Comment: Make sure you update your @model to reflect its of type `ViewModel`.